# Error when converting the varchar value 'A001' to the data type int

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm developing a SQL Server 2016 SP2 stored procedure that generates a JSON string.

When I run it, this piece of code:

```
set @batch = (
    select 1 as [BatchId], Value as [Name], (CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as varchar(34))) as [Created]
        from VariableData
        where VariableData.ProductionOrderId = @productionOrderId and VariableData.VariableDataId = 10
    for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
);
```

With these data:
[image]

Generates the following error:

> Error when converting the varchar value 'A001' to the data type int

But I don't understand why I get that message because I don't use `VariableDataId` column in the above sql code.

If there isn't any char in column `VariableDataId` (of type `varchar(4)`), I don't get any error.

Why do I get that error message?

Comment: `I don't use VariableDataId column in the above sql code` - what about the `and VariableData.VariableDataId = 10`?

Comment: Uppssss. I didn't notice it.

Comment: Please, vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't understand why I get that message because I don't use VariableDataId column in the above sql code.

Actually you are, in the where condition `VariableData.VariableDataId = 10`. It is causing an implicit conversion to int for all values in that column.

Just modify the comparison to `VariableData.VariableDataId = '10'` (where '10' is a string/varchar), and the implicit conversion will not be performed.

Answer (score 0):

You refer to VariableDataId column in line 4 of your query

```
where VariableData.ProductionOrderId = @productionOrderId and VariableData.VariableDataId = 10
```

You have two options. First, use the correct data type in the predicate.

```
where VariableData.ProductionOrderId = @productionOrderId and VariableData.VariableDataId = '10'
```

Second, convert column with TRY_CAST/TRY_CONVERT if you want to use INT value as the condition.

```
where VariableData.ProductionOrderId = @productionOrderId and TRY_CAST(VariableData.VariableDataId AS INT) = 10
```

I recommend the first option.